# Javascript not always loading

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, flexslider, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a simple home page slider that I am trying to get up. I have tried it with flexslider and a few other slider javascript scripts.  What's weird is that it loads just great on the first page load and if I do a hard refresh it.  In both instances it loads as you would expect.  However, if you click away from the page with the slider and then back to the page (without doing a hard refresh), the slider doesn't show up at all.

I'm on a new rails 4.0.0 app.

I have placed the flexslider and other slider jquery code in the vender/assets/javascript directory.  Then in the app/assets/javascript/pages.js.coffee page I have:

```
$(document).ready ->
  $(".flexslider").flexslider animation: "slide"
```

I've also changed it around to:

```
$(window).load ->
  $(".flexslider").flexslider animation: "slide"
```

as well as:

```
$ ->
  $(".flexslider").flexslider animation: "slide"
```

but all result in the same problem.

Any idea what I might be missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem is because you have turbolinks gem, which only loads part or page, not all of it. So `document.ready` event does not work. You could try this:

```
$(window).bind 'page:change', ->
  $(".flexslider").flexslider animation: "slide"
```

Comment: or you just can connect the [jquery-turbolinks](https://github.com/kossnocorp/jquery.turbolinks) gem.

Comment: @Julius - This works perfectly when I go back to the page.  There is a problem now though when it loads initially it doesn't work in the same way going back to the page didn't work before.